# Display an existing PDF using TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to generate PDF and display them in the page where I am generating it.
I have given the user the choice to archive the pdf to file. In my application there a section that shows all the archived files. So my problem is, whow do I use TCPDF to just display an existing PDF file and display it in an iFrame.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<embed>` tag of your iframe page to prevent it from download.

Link tcpdf.php on `src` attribute of `<embed>`

```
<html>
<body>
<embed
type="application/pdf"
src="http://yoursite.com/tcpdf/tcpdf.php″
width="100%"
height="100%">
</embed>
</body>
</html>
```